# Calling JavaFx from javaScript

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

Is it possible to call JavaFx application from javaScript? Now i'm able to call an html file from javaFX using

```
  webview = new WebView();
  webview.setVisible(true);
  webengine = webview.getEngine();
  webengine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  File file = new File("C:\\sample.html");
  System.out.println(file.exists() + " file exitence");
  webengine.load(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
```

if possible please help me. i'm new to java and JavaFx.

Comment: read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/js-javafx.htm

Comment: You need execute a part of code in your script or run a jar from your script ?

Answer (score 1):

In JS: alert("HEAD;DATA");

In Java:

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

engine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
    public void handle(WebEvent<String> e) {
        String[] infs = e.getData().split(";");

        if(infs[0].equals("HEAD")){
            System.out.println(infs[1]);
        }
    }
});
```